# How to Add a "all button" to add all term in a SharePoint Managed Metadata site column

Tags: sharepoint, taxonomy-terms

In a sharePoint site, we have a lot of Managed Metadata site column. I want to alow users to store all term using a button. [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khkWS.jpg)

Is there a solution to this need? What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: My question is not userful or not clear? no research effort??

Comment: I find it neither useful, nor clear, nor showing any research effort.

Comment: Ok.. This subject is very complex (i search for a long time about 2 weeks) ... my english is bad... im  a french guy .. may be i m not clear... I think this functionality is very usefull. (but you have to be a SharePoint developer).

Comment: I think the sample image is clear no?

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic the answer is below

Answer (score 0):

There is not a OOTB method to achieve it, we have to do customize to achieve it.

In SharePoint 2013 server, find the "WebTaggingDialog.aspx" page in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS".

Then copy this file to backup it, open this file using Notepad, and add the following code into "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead", and save it.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {      
        $("button[title='Add the highlighted item to this field']").after('<button class="wt-addbutton wt-float-left" id="AddAllToFieldEditor" onclick="addToAllFieldControl();return false;">Select All &gt;&gt;</button>');      
    });
    function addToAllFieldControl() {
        $("ul.TmtTree>li>ul>li").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var text = $(this).text();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.WebTaggingDialog.get_$2().addTerm(id, text);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Dennis Guo give me this answer on this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/832217ff-291c-4c5b-aaba-a12334b3ae07/how-to-add-a-8220all-button8221-to-add-all-term-in-a-sharepoint-managed-metadata-site-column?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required)